# how can I change the subpage after filling the form in spring?

Tags: java, spring

I have a `html` form:

```
<form action="login" th:action="@{/login}" th:object="${user}" method="post">
    <p>login: <input type="text" th:field="*{login}" /></p>
    <p>pass: <input type="password" th:field="*{pass}" /></p>
    <p><input type="submit" value="Submit" /> <input type="reset" value="Reset" /></p>
</form>
```

and the controller for it looks like:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/login", method= RequestMethod.GET)
public String userForm(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("user", new user());
    return "login";
}

@RequestMapping(value="/login", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String customerSubmit(@ModelAttribute User user, Model model) {

    model.addAttribute("user", user);
    return "result";
}
```

When user goes to my page `http://localhost:8080/login` he can see the login form. When he fills it, he is seeing the `result` page:

```
<body>
<h1>Result</h1>
<p th:text="'login: ' + ${user.login}" />
<p th:text="'pass: ' + ${user.pass}" />
</body>
```

and the data above is filled from the form. However, the browser url still shows `http://localhost:8080/login` instead of `.../result`. How come and how can I change it? Also, how can I use his login on the result page? I tried to write a `ResultController` with the following method:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/result", method= RequestMethod.GET)
public String userForm(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("user", new User());
    return "result";
}
```

but with the current configuration it is not hooked up to my `result.html` page. How can I use the provided `user` and `pass` from form on `login.html` page in the code for `result.html`?

Comment: Form's action attribute is "login" so, it won't go to "result"

Comment: @hashmap but when I change it to result and leave the rest of the code intact, then I’m getting null values on result page